# Using rvest to scrape specific html table using the heading name

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Trying to scrape the data from a specific table of building permit information. The following code works for most of the building permits I am looping through:

```
library(rvest)

permit_numbers <- c("BP125602", "BP125473", "BP125472")

URL <- paste("https://www.nanaimo.ca/WhatsBuilding/Folder", permit_numbers, sep = "/")

task_table <- lapply(URL, function(x) {
    x %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_table() %>%
    .[[3]] %>%
    .[["Task"]]
})
```

However sometimes the task information is not located in the third table on the page. For example, https://www.nanaimo.ca/WhatsBuilding/Folder/BP125721 
the task information is in the second table.

**How can I scrape the information with column heading "Task", regardless of where it is on the page?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(rvest)
URL <- "https://www.nanaimo.ca/WhatsBuilding/Folder/BP125602"

tables <- URL %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table()


task_table <- lapply(tables, function(x) if(names(x) == "Task"){x})

task_table[sapply(task_table, is.null)] <- NULL
task_table <- task_table[[1]][["Task"]]
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Ah I see, I was thinking that I needed to identify it using html_nodes(), but this works, thank-you. I have updated my orginal question to include multiple building permits. Do you mind showing how you would nest your suggestion within the existing loop? It seems like I should be able to just plug it in, but I'm obviously missing something